# How to register XLL add-in programmatically?

Tags: excel, add-in

How I can register XLL add-in programmatically?

Comment: Do you mean load the XLL add-in in Excel, or register it in the registry as an installed add-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Application.RegisterXLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837989.aspx) works for me

Answer (score 0):

[How To Build an Add-in (XLL) for Excel Using Visual C++](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178474)

[Excel xll Add-in Development - Excel REGISTER() Function](http://www.codematic.net/excel-development/excel-xll/excel-xll-register.htm)